# Google Sheets - Bundle a number of goods together, then calculate

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to calculate profits from bundles of products. The products have different prices and I am struggling to find a way to automate the process.

I would like the product to be listed on a single row containing Product Name, Bundle Name, Bundle Purchase Price, Product Selling Price, Bundle Selling Price.

Bundlename A,B,C,D.. (Or whatever) bundles an otherwise undefined amount of products into the same Bundle Price. Once a product has been sold, I can write the Product Selling Price, which will add to the Bundle Selling Price, until the entire Bundle has been sold.

I don't know how to make Google Sheets determine which products are linked to the Bundle Price, without having to manually determine the rows involved in the calculation. Imagine if I were to add a second Bundle, B, with a new Bundle Price below the rows of Bundle Name A. How would I make it understand, that after A follows B, and it should now search for Bundle Name B when calculating profit from Bundle Price to Bundle Selling Price?

As a side note: This is a side-gig I do in my spare time. I could type it in manually, but I do like it, when things are looking smooth and are easy to handle.

Hope I can get some help here.

Kind regards,

Jonas

[image: For visualization purposes]

Comment: Did you try `=sumif() ?`

Comment: _How would I make it understand, that after A follows B_ Telepathy? Seriously, I think you have it back-to-front. I would have a lists of Bundles, a product Name for the Bundle and each of the items that are included in the bundle; you could use vlookup (or similar) to get the values of the individual bundle items, then sum them to get the Bundle Price, add a columns/cells for Bundle Selling Price.